Crop map image using geometry_mask(rasterio) but get an empty image
Trying to crop map using geometry_mask and block, mmap to control memory usage,
this image may show what I want to do
enter image description here
but now my code returns an empty image,because the for loop don't get any data.
I have already test several times,it looks like wrong block mask causes this?(not really sure)
import os
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from rasterio.features import geometry_mask
from shapely.wkt import loads


def apply_mask_and_crop(polygon, map_image, transform_parameters, block_size=1024):
    # Load polygon from wkt strings
    polygon = loads(polygon)
    # Initialize boundaries
    ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax = float('inf'), 0, float('inf'), 0
    # Generate the transform
    west, south, east, north, map_width, map_height = transform_parameters
    transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(west, south, east, north, map_width, map_height)
    # Apply mask in blocks and find the bounding box of the mask
    for y in range(0, map_image.shape[0], block_size):
        for x in range(0, map_image.shape[1], block_size):
            y_end = min(y + block_size, map_image.shape[0])
            x_end = min(x + block_size, map_image.shape[1])
            # Generate the mask for the current block
            block_mask = geometry_mask([polygon], out_shape=(y_end - y, x_end - x), transform=transform, invert=True)
            # Apply the block mask directly to the map_image
            map_image[y:y_end, x:x_end][~block_mask] = 0
            # Update boundaries if there are any masked areas in the current block
            if np.any(block_mask):
                y_coords, x_coords = np.where(block_mask)
                ymin = min(ymin, y + y_coords.min())
                ymax = max(ymax, y + y_coords.max())
                xmin = min(xmin, x + x_coords.min())
                xmax = max(xmax, x + x_coords.max())
    # Ensure valid boundaries
    if ymin == float('inf'):
        ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = 0, 0, 0, 0
    # Crop the image to the determined bounding box
    if ymin < ymax and xmin < xmax:
        cropped_image = map_image[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
    else:
        cropped_image = np.empty((0, 0), dtype=map_image.dtype)
    # Calculate the geographic coordinates of the top-left and bottom-right
    top_left_geo = (ymin * transform.e + transform.f, xmin * transform.a + transform.c)
    bottom_right_geo = (ymax * transform.e + transform.f, xmax * transform.a + transform.c)
    return cropped_image, top_left_geo, bottom_right_geo


# Generate test data
multipolygon = "Multipolygon(((123 43,124 43,124 44,123 44,123 43)))"
image_shape, block_size = (24000, 24000, 3), 1024
image = np.memmap('temp', dtype=np.uint8, mode='w+', shape=image_shape)
for y in range(0, image_shape[0], block_size):
    for x in range(0, image_shape[1], block_size):
        y_end = min(y + block_size, image_shape[0])
        x_end = min(x + block_size, image_shape[1])
        block_data = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(y_end - y, x_end - x, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        image[y:y_end, x:x_end] = block_data
cropped_image, top_left_geo, bottom_right_geo = apply_mask_and_crop(multipolygon, image, (122.8, 42.5, 124.3, 44.2, 24000, 24000))
# Show image
plt.imshow(cropped_image)
plt.title("Image")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
image._mmap.close()
os.remove('temp')

What's the mistake in my code and how to fix?

Can you describe why you are traversing your image in blocks? It doesn't appear in your image description.
